# Ask an actor and let him respond when he reaches a particular state in Akka 2

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm quite new to Akka so my question may seem simple:

I have an actor called `workerA` that uses [FSM](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fsm.html) and can thus be either in those two states `Finished`and `Computing`:

```
sealed trait State
case object Finished extends State
case object Computing extends State

sealed trait Data
case object Uninitialized extends Data
case class Todo(target: ActorRef, queue: immutable.Seq[Any]) extends Data
```

When `workerA` receives `GetResponse` it should answer if and if only it is in state `Finished`.

What is the proper way of doing this? I know we should avoid to be blocking in this paradigm but here it is only the top actor which is concerned.
Thanks

Comment: Looks simple or I dont understand question. What should it do when it is not in Finished state

Comment: while not in Finished states the actor gather information from various other actors in order to create the result which is to be sent to the sender of GetResponse. Give your answer even if you think its simple .thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not necessarily sure you even need FSM here.  FSM is a really good tool for when you have many states and many possible (and possibly complicated) state transitions between those states.  In your case, if I understand correctly, you basically have two states; gathering data and finished.  It also seems that there is only a single state transition, going from `gathering -> finished`.  If I have this all correct, then I'm going to suggest that you simply use `become` to solve your problem.

I have some code below to show a trivial example of what I'm describing.  The basic idea is that the main actor farms some work off to some workers and then waits for the results.  If anyone asks for the results while the work is being done, the actor stashes that request until the work is done.  When done, the actor will reply back to anyone that has asked for the results.  The code is as follows:

```
case object GetResults
case class Results(ints:List[Int])
case object DoWork

class MainActor extends Actor with Stash{
  import context._

  override def preStart = {
    val a = actorOf(Props[WorkerA], "worker-a")
    val b = actorOf(Props[WorkerB], "worker-b")
    a ! DoWork
    b ! DoWork
  }

  def receive = gathering(Nil, 2)

  def gathering(ints:List[Int], count:Int):Receive = {
    case GetResults => stash()
    case Results(i) =>      
      val results = i ::: ints
      val newCount = count - 1
      if (newCount == 0){
        unstashAll()
        become(finished(results))        
        child("worker-a") foreach (stop(_))
        child("worker-b") foreach (stop(_))
      }
      else
        become(gathering(results, newCount))
  } 

  def finished(results:List[Int]):Receive = {
    case GetResults => sender ! results
  }
}

class WorkerA extends Actor{
  def receive = {
    case DoWork =>

      //Only sleeping to simulate work.  Not a good idea in real code
      Thread sleep 3000
      val ints = for(i <- 2 until 100 by 2) yield i
      sender ! Results(ints.toList)
  }
}

class WorkerB extends Actor{
  def receive = {
    case DoWork =>

      //Only sleeping to simulate work.  Not a good idea in real code
      Thread sleep 2000  
      val ints = for(i <- 1 until 100 by 2) yield i
      sender ! Results(ints.toList)      
  }
}
```

Then you could test it as follows:

```
val mainActor = system.actorOf(Props[MainActor])
val fut = mainActor ? GetResults
fut onComplete (println(_))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pattern match on FSM states:

```
// insert pattern matching stuff instead of ...

class MyActor extends Actor with FSM[State, Message] {
  startWith(Finished, WaitMessage(null))

  when(Finished) {
    case Event(Todo(... =>
      // work
      goto(Computing) using Todo(...)
    case Event(GetResponse(... =>
      // reply: sender ! msg // or similar
  }

  /* the rest is optional. You can use onTransition below to send yourself a message to    report status of the job: */
  when(Busy) {
    case Event(Finished(... =>
      // reply to someone: sender ! msg // or similar
      goto(Finished)
  }

  onTransition {
    case Finished -> Computing =>
      // I prefer to run stuff here in a future, and then send a message to myself to signal the end of the job:
      self ! Finished(data)
  }
```

An Edit to more specifically address the question:

```
class MyActor extends Actor with FSM[State, Message] {
  startWith(Finished, WaitMessage(null))

  when(Finished) {
    case Event(Todo(... =>
      // work
      goto(Computing) using Todo(...)
    case Event(GetResponse(... =>
      // reply: sender ! msg // or similar
      stay
  }

  initialize()
}
```

Comment: yes but what happens if MyActor gets `GetResponse` while it is Busy?

Comment: What should happen then is dependent on your requirements. You can ignore GetResponse until you enter the Finished state, or you can use the Stash trait to postpone processing of GetResponse messages. In any case a slightly more specific question would help (i.e: what do you want to do).

Comment: @Mermoz If you not handling a specific message in specific state it gets passed to whenUnhandled {} block, which will just get ignored in your case. Take a look at documentation here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fsm.html.

Comment: @Endre Varga: thanks `stash` is what I was looking for! @ A I fgfgf thanks for the info that info.